# Printing a single time Jslider

Tags: java, slider

What this code does is print a message every time that the knob of the slider passes between 0-20, and 20-50 (print one message when the knob is in 1, 2, 3, 4 so on). What I need is print just one time when the knob is between these ranges.

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
    {
        int sliderValue = jslider.getValue();  //This method returns the value of the Slider!
        if(sliderValue >= 0 && sliderValue <= 20)
        {
            System.out.println("Between 0 and 20");
        }
        else if (sliderValue > 20 && sliderValue <= 50)
        {
            System.out.println("You're 20 - 50");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your case you have a "**RANGE**" specified for time intervals which means

as soon as slider enter lower limit i.e. [sliderValue >= 0] OR [sliderValue > 20] your condition gets fulfilled and remains true until it exit the upper limit i.e.
[sliderValue <= 20] OR [sliderValue <= 50].

The notion is to set the limits first , you may set upper limit exclusive.

One of the solution may be to make the median of ranges as the target for success.

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    int sliderValue = jslider.getValue();
    int lowerMedian=(0+20)/2;
    int upperMedian=(0+50)/2;
    if (sliderValue >= 0 && sliderValue <= 20 && sliderValue == lowerMedian) {
        System.out.println("Between 0 and 20");
    } else if (sliderValue > 20 && sliderValue <= 50 && sliderValue == upperMedian) {
        System.out.println("You're 20 - 50");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
private boolean range0Printed = false;
private boolean range1Printed = false;

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{
    int sliderValue = jslider.getValue();  //This method returns the value of the Slider!
    if(sliderValue >= 0 && sliderValue <= 20 && !range0Printed)
    {
        System.out.println("Between 0 and 20");
        range0Printed = true;
    }
    else if (sliderValue > 20 && sliderValue <= 50 && !range1Printed)
    {
        System.out.println("You're 20 - 50");
        range1Printed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cohen, Would you mind to take my answer as the correct answer (I mean check it)... thanks